# Obj-C error: "expected unqualified-id before class pointer"

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, core-audio, objective-c++

I am currently working on a iOS development project. For convenience I split the features in several small programs in early stage. The project consists of Obj-C, Obj-C++ and C++ programs. Right now I am putting all them together into the final product and encountered some strange behaviors in terms of (I guess) compatibility between Obj-C and C++.

I am trying to initialize an object in an obj-C++ program, which comes from an obj-C class. But I keep getting error when compiling the obj-C class header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class AVAssetExportSession;

@interface LibraryImport : NSObject {
AVAssetExportSession * export;   //Error line
NSError* movieFileErr;
}
//class methods
```

The transcript goes like this:

LibraryImport.h:24: error: expected unqualified-id before 'export'

LibraryImport.h:24: error: instance variable 'unnamed' has unknown size

LibraryImport.h:24: error: expected `;' before 'export'

The call goes like this in the obj-C++ file: (No error detected here, just feel something might related)

```
LibraryImport* import = [[LibraryImport alloc] init];
```

The weirdest part is that when it was originally called by a pure Obj-C program, it works really fine. But the project nature needs to change the caller to obj-C++. And also, when I tried to change the obj-C file to obj-C++, I got even more errors than before, including the existing one.

Here are the questions that keep me banging my head against the wall for the past whole week:

1. In this case, how I can successfully initialize this object?
2. Is this problem related to compatibility between obj-C and C++? If so, is there a general solution or some clear explanation on the compatibility?

Let me know if more information is needed (It's my first time encountering this problem and I don't even know where to start...). Any insight will be appreciated. Thank you very much :-)

Cheers,

Manca

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Obj-C++, just C++.

Some compilers see `export` as a keyword, try naming your variable differently.

Comment: In fact, `export` is a C++ keyword: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14

Comment: Not always. I haven't found it, for example, in Visual Studio 2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx , although the IDE is still marking it as if it was one. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Did you check @larsmans' link? It's a keyword, but not well supported. Not sure that VS is really the best place to look to clear up confusion about language standards...